# PrintPreview shows nothing

Tags: c++, qt

I can't see anything in QT's QPrintPreviewDialog window, why is that? What's missing?

```
   QPrinter printer;
   printer.setOutputFileName("sample.pdf");
   printer.setPaperSize(QPrinter::A4);
   printer.setFullPage(true);
   QPainter painter(&printer);



   painter.drawLine(10, 10, 200, 200);

   QPrintPreviewDialog * preview = new QPrintPreviewDialog(&printer, this);

   if (preview->exec() == QDialog::Accepted)
   {

   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not how it is [documented](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprintpreviewdialog.html#details) to use `QPrintPreviewDialog`, the  documentation clearly states that after constructing the `QPrinterPreviewDialog` with your `QPrinter` object and before calling `QPrintPreviewDialog::exec()`, you should connect `paintRequested()` signal to a custom slot (where you should paint on your associated `QPrinter` object, and everything you paint there gets displayed in the `QPrintPreviewDialog`).

So, if I understand what you are trying to do right, you should define a slot `PreviewPaintRequest` and use `QPainter` there, your code should be something like this:

in your constructor:

```
QPrinter printer;
printer.setOutputFileName("sample.pdf");
printer.setPaperSize(QPrinter::A4);
printer.setFullPage(true);


QPrintPreviewDialog * preview = new QPrintPreviewDialog(&printer, this);
connect(preview, SIGNAL(paintRequested(QPrinter*)), this, SLOT(PreviewPaintRequested(QPrinter*)));
if (preview->exec() == QDialog::Accepted)
{

}
```

in `PreviewPaintRequested(QPrinter* printer)` slot:

```
{
    QPainter painter(printer);
    painter.drawLine(10, 10, 200, 200);
}
```

Comment: Figured it out myself, found it in 5-6. example i checked. Sorry because forgot to answer the question, and thank you did it. Hope it will help to someone.